# Fixing a bad JSON grammar

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, parsec

I've just started learning about parsing, and I wrote [this simple parser](http://hpaste.org/55972) in Haskell (using parsec) to read JSON and construct a simple tree for it. I am using the grammar in [RFC 4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627).

However, when I try parsing the string `{"x":1 }`, I'm getting the output:

```
parse error at (line 1, column 8):
unexpected "}"
expecting whitespace character or ","
```

This only seems to be happening when I have spaces before a closing brace (]) or mustachio (}).

What have I done wrong? If I avoid whitespace before a closing symbol, it works perfectly.

Comment: Slightly unrelated: the syntax highlighting at pastebin is not brilliant. There's actually a haskell version of pastebin: hpaste.org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parsec doesn't do rewinding and backtracking automatically. When you write `sepBy member valueSeparator`, the `valueSeparator` consumes white space, so the parser will parse your value like so:

```
{"x":1 }
[------- object
%        beginObject
 [-]     name
    %    nameSeparator
     %   jvalue
      [- valueSeparator
       X In valueSeparator: unexpected "}"

Legend:
[--]     full match
%        full char match
[--      incomplete match
X        incomplete char match
```

When the `valueSeparator` fails, Parsec won't go back and try a different combination of parses, because one character has already matched in `valueSeparator`.

You have two options to solve your problem:

1. Since white space is insignificant in JSON, always consume white space *after* a significant token, never before. So, a `tok` should only consume white space after the char, so its definition is `tok c = char c *> ws` (`(*>)` from `Control.Applicative`); apply the same rule to all the other parsers. Since you'll never consume white space after having entered the "wrong parser" that way, you won't end up having to back-track.
2. Use back-tracking in Parsec by adding `try` in front of parsers that might consume more than one character, and that should rewind their input if they fail.

*EDIT:* updated ASCII graphic to make more sense.

Comment: What would be the nicest way (in-code) to fix this? Should I be abandoning sepBy in this case?

Comment: Also, the reason I have whitespace reading before and after a token is because that's what it says in the RFC =/

Comment: `sepBy` is fine if you choose one of the two options that I suggested. Specifically, `member 'sepBy' try valueSeparator` should work as expected (replace ' by `).

Comment: Yipee! It works! Thank you so much. I have the most ridiculous smile on my face right now. :) Any advice on where to use or not use try? I've never managed to fully wrap my head around it.

Comment: @Clark Gaebel - try to use `try` only for character level parsers. If you follow Tikhon Jelvis's advice to use the `ParsecToken` module a lot of the need for `try` should vanish. That said you may still need `try` for CharParsers - these are the Parsec equivalent to a scanner's tokens.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution would be to have all your parsers skip *trailing* whitespace. Check out `lexeme` (in `ParsecToken`) in the Parsec docs for a neat way to do this or just whip up a simple version yourself:

```
 lexeme parser = do result <- parser
                    spaces
                    return result
```

Then use this function on all of your tokens (like numerical literals). This way you only ever have to worry about the whitespace at the very beginning of an expression.

For more info about `ParsecToken` and friends, look at the "Lexical Analysis" section of the [Parsec docs](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/daan/download/parsec/parsec.html).

It makes sense to only skip whitespace *after* a token except at the very beginning where you can skip it manually. You should take this approach even if you end up not using the `ParsecToken` module.

It seems you already have `tok` which acts like my `lexeme` except it consumes whitespace on *both* sides. Change it to only consume whitespace *after* the token and just ignore the whitespace at the very beginning of the input manually. That should (ideally :)) fix the problem.

Comment: My code is at http://pastebin.com/ewGH7QMh. Click on "this simple parser" in my initial question.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the link the first time I read the question. I'm probably going to revise my answer a lot once I finish reading it.

Comment: Ah. I had more or less the same problem before and that's basically how I solved it, but my actual code was fairly different.